# Hadoop name node not starting

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to run hadoop as a root user, i executed namenode format command hadoop namenode -format. after that I tried to open hadoop daemons , but namenode is not starting. I run the command  hadoop namenode -importCheckpoint and it gives foll. error:

```
 14/09/15 01:25:55 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory /home/umaima/cloudera_namedir is not formatted.
14/09/15 01:25:55 INFO common.Storage: Formatting ...
14/09/15 01:25:55 ERROR namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed.
java.io.IOException: NameNode is not formatted.
at     org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:336)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.doImportCheckpoint(FSImage.java:531)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:375)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:110)
  at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:372)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:335)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:271)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:467)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1330)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1339)

14/09/15 01:25:55 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
 /************************************************************
 SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at umaima-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S510p/127.0.1.1
************************************************************/
```

I am stuck in this. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Before formatting the namenode, delete the tmp folder(contains datanode and namenode) and then format the namenode.

And then start the hadoop services.